# How to find rows where difference in date columns are 3 or more days?

Tags: comparison, operators

How do I find rows (what operator do I use) where the difference between two date columns (as shown below) is equal to or greater than 3 days? The example below will only return all greater than. I need to limit the rows to those that are 3 or more days. Then it would be good to add a column that shows the days difference count. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ver. 11 on SQL Server 9. I have searched on questions relating to time difference but have not found this specific situation. Thanks for any help with this.

```
SELECT        Id, LastContactDate, LastProfileReceivedDate
FROM            Location
WHERE        (Account_Id = '499') AND (LastContactDate > LastProfileReceivedDate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible queries to return the specified result. I'd do it like this:

```
   SELECT l.Id
        , l.LastContactDate
        , l.LastProfileReceivedDate
        , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,l.LastProfileReceivedDate,l.LastContactDate) AS days_diff
     FROM Location l 
    WHERE l.Account_Id = '499'
      AND l.LastContactDate >= LastProfileReceivedDate + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

---

**Followup:**

The SQL query above is for MySQL (the question is tagged with "mysql"), and that's entirely different than Microsoft SQL Server.

For Microsoft SQL Server, replace the MySQL `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function with the SQL Server `DATEDIFF` function, and replace the `+ INTERVAL 3 DAY` with the DATEADD function:

```
   SELECT l.Id
        , l.LastContactDate
        , l.LastProfileReceivedDate
        , DATEDIFF(DAY,l.LastProfileReceivedDate,l.LastContactDate) AS days_diff
     FROM Location l 
    WHERE l.Account_Id = '499'
      AND l.LastContactDate >= DATEADD(DAY,3,l.LastProfileReceivedDate)
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I ran it but got this error that TIMESTAMPDIFF is not a built-in function name. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ver. 11 on SQL Server 9.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect! My mishap putting the MySQL tag in; I've removed it. Using either dateadd or datediff works, but dateadd is more efficient and less confusing. Now I would like to Cast the datetime format of both these date columns to show in the January 23, 2015 style. I am working on it now, but if you read this before I can solve I would appreciate that answer as well. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Use the SQL Server `CONVERT` function, with an appropriate style argument. You;d have to consult the documentation to find the right one to use, it's been so long since I used SQL Server,  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx), If there's not an appropriate one, you'll probably need to concatenate a series of DATEPART expressions.  Maybe **107** is the style you want.

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work: SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), LastContactDate, 107)

Answer (score 0):

I used the information from the 1st answer and modified it to this and it worked:

SELECT        Id AS Dormo_ID, LastContactDate, LastProfileReceivedDate, DATEDIFF(day, LastProfileReceivedDate, LastContactDate) AS Days_Difference
FROM            Location
WHERE        (Account_Id = '499') AND (DATEDIFF(day, LastProfileReceivedDate, LastContactDate) > 2)